# can I make X-server to notify me only when cursor exactly where I need?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, xserver

Yep, I made window that I could click through (thanks #gtk+ at irc.gnome.org), now - how to make it hear `mouse_over`-event?
So, what exactly we did:

```
def set_mask(win):
    size=win.window.get_size()
    bitmap=gtk.gdk.Pixmap(win.window,size[0],size[1],1)

    cr = bitmap.cairo_create()
    cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
    cr.set_source_rgba(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
    cr.rectangle((0,0)+size)
    cr.fill()  

    win.window.input_shape_combine_mask(bitmap,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered myself that it is not possible. `notify-osd` in ubuntu uses poll for check where is the cursor.